# How to set a variable a users referal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create some stats and need to print a users referal site, or search keyword. How to get a Users referal site or search keyword with javascript and print it?

Comment: I haven't tryied anything, because I got no glue how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.referrer` ( some info on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer) or [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95229140) ).

***Edit :***

For search kewords work on the referrer, for example searching "hello world" on google gives a referrer like this if searching directly ( adress bar or search bar ) :

```
http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hello+world
```

But searching hello world typing in google is done with ajax ( the parameter is after the # in the hash ) and gives you a referrer like :

```
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffr.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHello_world&rct=j&q=hello%20world&ei=BkY8TrrHDsPO-QaDxZy8Ag&usg=AFQjCNGUmN0hpMDY4b1b1NVm_LSttMeUdQ&sig2=yngbng_Sdq78v6wEKxHq4Q
```

So you could just have to search the `&q` parameter and see if there is `/url?` replace `%20` by space, otherway replace `+` by space :

```
var keywords= "";
var referrer= document.referrer;
if(referrer.match(/^https?:\/\/(www|encrypted)\.google\.(be|fr|com)\//))
{
  keywords= referrer.replace(/^.+(\?.+&q=|\?q=)([^&]*)(&.*|$)$/,"$2");
  if(referrer.match(/^https?:\/\/(www|encrypted)\.google\.(be|fr|com)\/url\?/)) keywords= keywords.replace(/%20/g," ");
  else keywords= keywords.replace(/\+/g," ");
  keywords= decodeURIComponent(keywords);
}
```

For yahoo you get a referrer like :

```
http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7h83TzxOx1MAQUBXNyoA;_ylc=X1MDUCMyNzY2Njc5BF9yAzIEYW8DMQRjc3JjcHZpZANRSWRGdlVvRzd2NlZsSnZ4VFZnV0Rna3FVZmRDVWs0OFR6Y0FCZjNsBGZyA3lmcC10LTcwMQRmcjIDc2J0bgRuX2dwcwMxMARvcmlnaW4Dc3JwBHF1ZXJ5A2hlbGxvIHdvcmxkBHNhbwMxBHZ0ZXN0aWQDVklQMDI2?p=hello+world&fr2=sb-top&fr=yfp-t-701&type_param=
```

So you could add :

```
else if(referrer.match(/^http:\/\/search\.yahoo\.com\//))
{
  keywords= decodeURIComponent(document.referrer.replace(/^.+(\?.+&p=|\?p=)([^&]*)(&.*|$)$/,"$2").replace(/\+/g," "));
}
```

The `decoreURIComponent` is for special chars ( +, #, & and foreign characters ).

And you will have the keywords from yahoo or google ( but you could change google domains  ( the `(be|fr|com)` ) and treat the case of other search motor.

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = document.referrer; 
alert(string);
```

this will give you address of referrer site

Answer (score 1):

The referring can be printed with:

```
document.write(document.referrer);
```

You may want to check out the documentation [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To get the referrer, use `document.referrer`

If you need to use JQuery to do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
 });
```

Comment: Rails: Examine the referrer string for typical search strings, like a Google URL, and parse the search keywords out.

Comment: @Rails beginner nice question !